# Trying to smooth edges with normal map

Tags: modeling, normal-map

I recently started using Blender and made my first character model, after that, I retopologized the model to make it low-poly for games. Now I want to smooth polygon edges of my low-poly model and so I found out that I can fake smooth edges with normal maps. I've baked the normal map from the high poly model but the edges on the low-poly model are still sharp.

High-poly:

[image: High-poly]

Low-poly:

[image: High-poly]

Normal map:

[image: Normal map]

Low-poly with normal map:

[image: Low-poly with normal map]


What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share your node group please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your low poly mesh does not have smooth shading enabled. You can enable it again by selecting your low-poly mesh, then pressing W -> Shade Smooth or going to Object -> Shade Smooth.

Comment: Yeah, I know but how do I "shade smooth" in other software, for example in a game engine? I thought this "smooth" info is stored in the normal map.

Comment: Oh i get it, this 'shade smooth' info is stored in the fbx file. Haha, so stupid. :D